# Replacing single space between regexp

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace a space between two alphanumeric characters and have come up with this:

```
sed -i -e '/^device/ s/[0-9a-zA-Z]\s[0-9a-zA-Z]/g' file.txt
```

Where file.txt looks like :

```
device    : Nxx2k PNP@0.6
device    : Pdot3 ICB@2.5
```

etc. I'd like for the spaces between the strings to the right of the colon to be replaced with an underscore _

```
device    : Nxx2k_PNP@0.6
device    : Pdot3_ICB@2.5
```

This command replaces the space and the two surrounding characters with the underscore. How can i make it such that only the space is repalced? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups to preserve the alphanumeric characters around the space:

```
sed -i -e '/^device/ s/\([0-9a-zA-Z]\) \([0-9a-zA-Z]\)/\1_\2/' file.txt
```

I used a space instead of `\s` because you wrote to replace "space",
and not "whitespace".
Also, `\s` is not supported with all versions of `sed`, so it's not portable (doesn't work with BSD sed).

Finally, I dropped the `g` flag because it's unnecessary in your examples.
If in your real use case you want to replace multiple spaces on one line,
then of course you should add it back.